# AC_CHECK_HEADER fail if the header install path has api in it

Tags: c++, autotools, autoconf

One of the header file for example BamReader.h from the bamtools package is install at

```
/usr/local/include/bamtools/api
```

I have tried to set the include flag to either:

```
CXXFLAGS="$CXXFLAGS -I/usr/local/include/bamtools"
or
CXXFLAGS="$CXXFLAGS -I/usr/local/include/bamtools/api"
AC_CHECK_HEADERS([BamReader.h], [bamtools_found=yes], [AC_MSG_ERROR([Unable to find bambools header])])
```

If I check the config.log file, the first one gave me an error:

```
configure:3837: g++ -c -g -O2 -I/usr/local/include/bamtools  conftest.cpp >&5
conftest.cpp:54:23: fatal error: BamReader.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

The second gave me the following error:

```
configure:3837: g++ -c -g -O2 -I/usr/local/include/bamtools/api  conftest.cpp >&5
In file included from conftest.cpp:54:0:
/usr/local/include/bamtools/api/BamReader.h:13:28: fatal error: api/api_global.h: No such file or directory
 #include "api/api_global.h"^M
                            ^
compilation terminated.
configure:3837: $? = 1
```

The problem is with BamReader.h trying to include api/api_global.h

Answer (score 0):

I got a simple fix by putting the api into the AC_CHECK_HEADERS the it worked.

```
CXXFLAGS="$CXXFLAGS -I/usr/local/include/bamtools"
AC_CHECK_HEADERS([api/BamReader.h], [bamtools_found=yes], [AC_MSG_ERROR([Unable to find bambools header])])

configure output
checking api/BamReader.h usability... yes
```

Essentially, you have to use the library by appending api/ to every header.  Please comment: is this a good practice?

Comment: It is common, for libraries to require to only include their base path rather than the subdirectories, to avoid naming conflicts with standard headers or headers coming from other libraries.

Comment: Using the word "api" in the directory name of a library's headers is bad practice. The header should ideally be called `<bamtools/BamReader.h>`.

Comment: Agree with Roland's comment.  api is such a generic term, it is useless.